# QCAR on ASUS Transformer (eee Pad)

Tags: android, augmented-reality, transformer-model

I'm starting to develop an AR applcation and my development device is the one in the subject.
This target runs Android 3.1.

i covered all the steps needed to setup my environment and tried to run the Image Targets example that is supplied with the QCAR SDK but with no success.

Everything is complied and deployed successfully but when the application starts on the target i get an error:
"Network connection required to initialize camera settings.
Please check your connection and restart the application.
If you are still experiencing problems, then your device may not be currently supported." 
While a network connection is present via Wi-fi to a local home network.

Anyone can suggest me what to do? I cannot replace my device and i must work with Quallcom's AR library.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Soon apparently..
https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/forums

Answer (score 1):

According to [Qualcomm](https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/support_file/download/Android/supported%20devices%20android/Supported_Device_Android.pdf), the QCAR SDK now supports all android Eclair, Froyo, Gingerbread, and Honeycomb devices.

I found [this thread](https://ar.qualcomm.at/arforums/showthread.php?t=452&highlight=xoom), which lists four sanity checks:

1. Is your device connected to a wifi network with an internet connection?
2. Can you load a webpage using the Browser app?
3. Can you load an webpage at an https address?
4. Is the date and time on your device are set correctly?